# Doing math operations with bytes

Tags: java, arrays, byte, packet, checksum

I need to do some math operations (+, - and mod) with bytes saved inside an array/packet. Practically I need to create a checksum for a packet using some specific ck rules (sum of all the bytes in the packet -> sum mod 100(256 in dec.) -> FD - mod). The problem is that all the automatic java conversion in integer creates wrong results (checked manually).

How can I do this?

EDIT: 
thanks for the answers! 
Added some rapid test code (sorry but I can't post the original code).

I've just added the 0xFF mask in the for-cycle and the ck is right, but the other output are wrong. If you want to give me some more hints I'm here :D ready to learn!

thanks

the input:

```
    input byte[] packet = {(byte)0x80, (byte)0x11, (byte)0x30, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x46, (byte)0x56, (byte)0x57, (byte)0x30, (byte)0x38, (byte)0x30,
        (byte)0x35, (byte)0x45, (byte)0x52, (byte)0x00};
```

the ck calculator method:

```
  byte ckCalculator(byte[] b) {

    int len = b.length;
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        sum = sum + b[i]&0xFF;      
    }

    System.out.println(String.format("%02X ", sum));

    int module = sum % 256;

    System.out.println(String.format("%02X ", module));

    int diff = 253 - module;

    byte ck = (byte)diff;
    System.out.println(String.format("%02X", ck));
    return ck;
}
```

output:
sum : 1A
module: 1A
**ck : E3**

expected output:
sum: 31A
module: 1A
**ck: E3**

Comment: show your code.  typically `int foo = 0xFF & b;` is the trick to work with unsigned bytes in java.

Comment: Java is not great for this but it can clearly do it.  To focus the question, post some specific examples, with what you get and what you expect.

Comment: thanks for the answers! added some test code, input, output and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses ;).

```
sum = sum + (b[i] & 0xFF);
```

or better

```
sum += b[i] & 0xFF;
```

BTW

```
System.out.println(String.format("%02X ", sum));
```

can be written as: (note %n for newline)

```
System.out.printf("%02X %n", sum);
```

Comment: aaaaaaargh damned parentheses!!XD Thanks a lot! I've updated the code a lot of time with a lot of different strategies and probably I've lost them XD
The abbreviate version of the consecutive sum makes me uncomfortable when the things goes wrong :D so I tend to use the long one (yes I know, it's like an OCD :P).
Thanks again. (I've tried to give you and the other users some votes up but i can't :-/ lv.1 character...need some exp)

Comment: I do not need extra points - in fact the solution is trivial, something easily overlooked.